# How to create conditional behaviour with pam_exec and PAM_TYPE?

Tags: linux, pam

I want to implement conditions for PAM_TYPE open_session and close_session. With this I can trigger different actions at different times for login and logout.

I have a script which tests for the variable PAM_TYPE and give appropriate exit codes: exit 0 for success and exit 1 otherwise.

But I get weird problems with the assembly; pam_exec don't get the right exit codes from the script.

Here is my implementation for testing:

In `/etc/pam.d/common-session` I have added:

```
session [success=ignore default=1] pam_exec.so debug seteuid /usr/sbin/test.sh logout
session optional        pam_exec.so debug log=/tmp/test_pam.txt /bin/echo "logout reached"
session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_exec.so debug seteuid /usr/sbin/test.sh logout
session optional        pam_exec.so  debug log=/tmp/test_pam.txt /bin/echo "login reached"
```

The script `/usr/sbin/test.sh` is

```
#!/bin/bash
# some actions
# invocted by pam_exec.so

echo $PAM_TYPE
case $1 in
logout)
  if [ $PAM_TYPE == "close_session" ]; then echo $PAM_TYPE; exit 0; else exit 1; fi
  ;;
esac
```

When I make a su to an user and immediately a logout I get in the log-file

```
$ cat /tmp/test_pam.txt 
*** Mon Jun  3 12:14:07 2019
"login reached"
*** Mon Jun  3 12:15:00 2019
"login reached"
```

This behavior is weird. The last line must be *logout reached*.
So Pam takes every time the condition to false. But for testing I have placed  `echo $PAM_TYPE;` in the true-condition and this echo is displayed in the terminal by logout. So the if Statement leads to *true* with `exit 0` but pam_exec takes it as false.

Has someone an idea what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Helge

Comment: Aren't you ignoring logout via `success=ignore`?

Comment: No, `ignore` means no action, continue; `default=1` means for anything else (other than `success`) skip `1` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this answer from another site:

> You cannot depend on jumps in PAM stack in the close_session calls. The pam module stack is "frozen" in the open_session and identical modules in the same order are invoked in the close_session call.

The behavior of my scripts is now clear: My approach is not possible!

Comment: Did you find another way to achieve this?

Comment: @OJFord No :-(   (Comments must be at least 15 chars - so I write this ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

in /etc/pam.d/sshd

> session required pam_exec.so /etc/pam_scripts/pam_exec.sh

where pam_exec.sh has something like

> if [ "$PAM_TYPE" == "open_session" ] &&  [ "$PAM_USER" != "root" ]; then
>
> ..do something
>
> else
>
> ..do something else
>
> fi
>
> exit 0